# How to read the next line in a text document?

Tags: c#, .net, file, streamreader

I want to know how to read the next line of a text document.
If I click the button, it should open the text document and read the first line.
Then, if I click the "next" button it should read the next line.
How can I do this second button? In C and other languages there are some commands for this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `StreamReader` object and then you can invoke [the `ReadLine` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx). Don't forget to add the "@" symbol before file path name.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\\YourPath.txt");
```

Then on your button clicks you can do:

```
var nextLine = sr.ReadLine();
```

The result of each line will be stored in the `nextLine` variable.

Comment: I am so stupid, I already used the ReadLine() command but forgot to save the line as the text of the label LOL but thank you and the other guys!

Comment: @iAmFastAndYou - glad you got it sort.  If the answers helped please mark one as the answer.

Comment: Do you know how to get back to the first line of the document?

Comment: @iAmFastAndYou - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053206/return-streamreader-to-beginning

Answer (score 4):

You can use [StreamReader.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx)

```
if (myStreamReader.Peek() >= 0) 
   {
      string line = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
   }
```

If you don't want to keep the file open, you can start by reading all lines into memory using [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx)

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```