# Read many of the StreamReader

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have little problem. My code in visual studio:

```
file = new StreamReader("D:\\BaseList.txt");
string line;
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(line);
}
file.Close(); // 1
file = new StreamReader("D:\\Baza3.txt");  //2
```

I read all lines in file and I would like once more to read from the beginning. Do I have to close the stream and reload the file to stream( line numbered 1 and 2)? 
Is there a method, which allows to set the stream at the beginning of my file without using this numbered line?

Comment: Why do you want to read the file several times instead of just saving the result in-memory and refering to it there? Do you expect the file-contents to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the position of the base stream like this

```
streamReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
```

You can do that only if the base stream is seekable. (`myStream.CanSeek == true`). The is true in your case when you create a new StreamReader with a path string.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `BaseStream` `Position` to 0, or copying the contents to a `MemoryStream` before actually start reading it.

Check out this thread:
[Return StreamReader to Beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2053206/5077593)